# plot_decision_regions with error "Filler values must be provided when X has more than 2 training features."

Tags: python-3.x, plot, svc, mlxtend

I am plotting 2D plot for SVC Bernoulli output.

converted to vectors from Avg word2vec and standerdised data
split data to train and test.
Through grid search found the best C and gamma(rbf)

```
clf = SVC(C=100,gamma=0.0001)

clf.fit(X_train1,y_train)

from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions



plot_decision_regions(X_train, y_train, clf=clf, legend=2)


plt.xlabel(X.columns[0], size=14)
plt.ylabel(X.columns[1], size=14)
plt.title('SVM Decision Region Boundary', size=16)
```

Receive error :-
ValueError: y must be a NumPy array. Found

also tried to convert the y to numpy. Then it prompts error
ValueError: y must be an integer array. Found object. Try passing the array as y.astype(np.integer)

finally i converted it to integer array.
Now it is prompting of error.
ValueError: Filler values must be provided when X has more than 2 training features.

Answer (score 5):

You can use PCA to reduce your data multi-dimensional data to two dimensional data. Then pass the obtained result in `plot_decision_region` and there will be no need of filler values.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions

clf = SVC(C=100,gamma=0.0001)
pca = PCA(n_components = 2)
X_train2 = pca.fit_transform(X_train)
clf.fit(X_train2, y_train)
plot_decision_regions(X_train2, y_train, clf=clf, legend=2)

plt.xlabel(X.columns[0], size=14)
plt.ylabel(X.columns[1], size=14)
plt.title('SVM Decision Region Boundary', size=16)
```

Comment: What is the interpretation of the two spatial axes when PCA is used? How would they be labeled?

Answer (score 2):

I've spent some time with this too as `plot_decision_regions` was then complaining `ValueError: Column(s) [2] need to be accounted for in either feature_index or filler_feature_values` and there's one more parameter needed to avoid this.

So, say, you have 4 features and they come unnamed:

```
X_train_std.shape[1] = 4
```

We can refer to each feature by their index 0, 1, 2, 3. You only can plot 2 features at a time, say you want `0` and `2`.

You'll need to specify one additional parameter (to those specified in @sos.cott's answer), **feature_index**, and fill the rest with fillers:

```
value=1.5
width=0.75

fig = plot_decision_regions(X_train.values, y_train.values, clf=clf,
              feature_index=[0,2],                        #these one will be plotted  
              filler_feature_values={1: value, 3:value},  #these will be ignored
              filler_feature_ranges={1: width, 3: width})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do  (Assuming X_train and y_train are still panda dataframes) for the numpy array problem.

```
plot_decision_regions(X_train.values, y_train.values, clf=clf, legend=2)
```

For the filler_feature issue, you have to specify the number of features so you do the following:

```
value=1.5
width=0.75

fig = plot_decision_regions(X_train.values, y_train.values, clf=clf,
                  filler_feature_values={2: value, 3:value, 4:value},
                  filler_feature_ranges={2: width, 3: width, 4:width},
                  legend=2, ax=ax)
```

You need to add one filler feature for each feature you have.